# How can I reloop this code?

Tags: java

My program requires the user to input a file name that they have in the working directory (which contains text) and then enter the output file name that is also already in the same directory. After that the user then must choose whether they want to Capitalize or lowercase all the text in the file.

Once they have chosen that they should be given the option to process another file. That's where I'm having trouble. After printing "Would you like to process another file? Y for Yes or N for No?" how do I Get it to loop back to the beginning?

Right now my code keeps looping back to the "Capitalize or lowercase all words" I need it to stop doing that and ask the user if they want to process another file, if so it needs to go back and ask the input and output file names again.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the input data file name:");
    String fileInput = sc.next();
    System.out.println("Please enter the output data file name:");
    String fileOutput = sc.next();
    while(true){
        System.out.println("A: Capitalize all words.\nB: Lowercase all words.");

        System.out.println("enter choice:");
        char choice = sc.next().charAt(0);
        if(choice == 'A'){
            capitalize(fileInput, fileOutput);
        }else{
            lowercase(fileInput, fileOutput);
        }

    }
   System.out.println("Process another file? Y for Yes or N for No");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to wrap all your code in the while loop, as follows; the while loop only repeats the code in it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (true) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the input data file name:");
        String fileInput = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter the output data file name:");
        String fileOutput = sc.next();
        System.out.println("A: Capitalize all words.\nB: Lowercase all words.");

        System.out.println("enter choice:");
        char choice = sc.next().charAt(0);
        if (choice == 'A') {
            capitalize(fileInput, fileOutput);
        } else {
            lowercase(fileInput, fileOutput);
        }

        System.out.println("Process another file? Y for Yes or N for No");
        String processAnother = sc.next();
        if (processAnother.equals("N") || processAnother.equals("n")) break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I kind of figured I would have to put all of the code into the while loop, I just didn't know I would have to add a new string for processing another. Thanks!